# How to download a file when a django function is called by javascript instead of navigation to the url?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I have a page where several buttons process different functions like sending a sms (via API), sends a file by email, or downloads a PDF file. Button actions dont use forms, but uses ajax requests via javascript.

I used to create a pdf file using javascript (jspdf), but have written code which generates a pdf file by python on the server. Now I need to allow download when the button is clicked.

Server code snippet:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b') as temp:
    from django.http import FileResponse
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(temp.name, pagesize=A4, rightMargin=20, leftMargin=20, topMargin=20, bottomMargin=20, allowSplitting=1, title="Prescription", author="MyOPIP.com")
    doc.build(elements)
    print(f'Generated {temp.name}')
    return FileResponse(open(temp.name, 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')
```

The above code is supposed to download a pdf file, if called by navigating to the url.

On my javascript side, I tried to determine what I'm receiving:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/clinic/${cliniclabel}/prescription/download/patient/${patient_id}`,
    dataType: "html",
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Received data from server..type is ", typeof(data))
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

And I get:

```
Received data from server..type is  string
%PDF-1.4
%���� ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
1 0 obj
<<
/F1 2 0 R /F2 5 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj....
```

Apparently django sends this as a file stream. How can I get the file downloaded to the user when the response is processed by javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do it through Ajax because JavaScript cannot save files directly to a user's computer (out of security concerns).

That being said, the work around would be to set the "src" of an anchor tag to the url for the file download and trigger a click on it.

**Note:** You'll have to change your function method from POST to GET

- Change the "button" to an "a" link and have `src="#"` in the html.
- Add an ng-click to it to trigger a JS function
- In the JS function, *do not call* `event.PreventDefault();` and then update the "src" of the "a" tag.
- Once function is done executing, then it'll trigger the normal click on the `<a>` tag anyway (with the source updated)

I haven't tested the above; so if that doesn't work, move the try the following:

- Keep the button as is
- Add a new hidden `<a>` tag with `src="#"`
- In the JS function, update the src of the `<a>` tag and trigger click on the element.

Comment under here if you have any questions.

Comment: Why not just add a `window.open` javascript method, and navigate to the new url?